# Why show error [ react-router-dom@5.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.]

Tags: reactjs

I wanna show page on using '`react-router-dom`' in react.

And show error

> [react-router-dom@5.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is
> installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.].

But my react version is `"^16.13.1"` already.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pra_hook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. But it got resolved when I use the below command:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Instead of

```
npm install -g react-router-dom.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do [npm install react-router-dom] and work